# Music location on windows form app problems

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

This code is working:

```
Music sound = new Music();

sound.Play(@"C:\Users\itama\Documents\Startech\HelperApplication\HelperApplication\data\music\alarmSound.mp3");
```

---

I have a question, how can I do that when I change computer / when someone install my app on another computer this location don't work. How can I make the location good for any pc that install on any location?

I tried to write it like this:

```
sound.Play(@"HelperApplication\data\music\alarmSound.mp3");
```

and it dont work

Does it can that i write like Properties.Rescources.filename.mp3 ?

Comment: Take a look at [Enviroment.GetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-8.0) function.

Comment: What type of application is it? Windows Forms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: its Windows From App C#

Comment: In WinForms, use `Application.StartupPath` to get the folder path from which the current application was run. That wi8ll work no matter where or how your app is installed.

Comment: I dont understand you.
Do i need to write:
sound.Play(Application.startupPath);
and?

Comment: And then `Path.Combine` with the relative part ("data/music/alarmsound.mp3").

Comment: thank you. two question

1. how t make my wndows from C# app only 1 exe file
2. does it work with only 1 exe file?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
// In your example work code write this before your code

string path = string.Empty;
try { path = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("mp3path.txt")[0].Trim(new char[] { ' ', '"', '@' }); }
catch { }

// And rewrite your code

Music sound = new Music();
sound.Play(path);

// In summary

string path = string.Empty;
try { path = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("mp3path.txt")[0].Trim(new char[] { ' ', '"', '@' }); }
catch { }

Music sound = new Music();
sound.Play(path);

// Compile your program to an executable-file.
// In the same folder in the same place as the
// executable-file of the program, create a text-file
// "mp3path.txt", and in this text-file indicate
// the path to mp3-file.

// You will have an executable-file, like "program.exe",
// and in the same folder there is a text-file "mp3path.txt",
// and in this text-file write path, for example:
// "C:\MyMusic\AlarmSound.mp3"
// And the path that you write in text-file "mp3path.txt"
// is the path for mp3-file.

// What you need?
// executable in folder
// mp3 in folder
// text-file in folder
// and path to mp3 in text-file
```